# office 365 DNS requirements

Tags: office365, exchange-server-2010

I have a LAN of few users (let's say 10) and they'd like to check their emails on the cloud.

We are running exchange 2010 on a Windows 2008 R2 Server using Active Directory Authentication so I guess I should buy an Exchange Online Plan on office365.com. However I have a question on the DNS, our server does not have an internet-facing IP, how should I proceed on this, should I buy a DynDNS account?

Answer (score 0):

I can only send you some information about that:
http://help.outlook.com/en-us/140/ff633682.aspx

http://www.msexchange.org/articles_tutorials/office-365/exchange-online/configuring-exchange-hybrid-deployment-migrating-to-office-365-exchange-online-part1.html

Answer (score 0):

Are you wanting to migrate your email to Office 365 and remove the internal exchange server?

If they just want to be able to access their email from a web browser then this is possible with Exchange 2010 already.
You'll need an SSL Certificate to avoid certificate error messages accessing OWA.
I would also contact your ISP about getting a static IP address. It shouldn't cost too much.

If you are migrating to Office 365 completely then you won't need a static IP but does take some planning and is very helpful to have someone on hand who has experience.

Answer (score 0):

The answer depends on whether you are looking to build a hybrid deployment or simply move them up to office365 and ditch the local Exchange server.

If you don't have a public facing IP I'd say it's safe to assume that you're using the exchange server strictly as local storage for your incoming emails. We see (and fix) this type of setup all the time.

The idea behind office365 is that it's accessible anywhere you have internet so unless you want a hybrid deployment you won't need to get a static IP or dynamic DNS account to use it.